# How to make nvidia command permanent

Tags: nvidia, startup

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with an Nvidia GeForce GT620 video card. As I'm running it through an older LG DLP tv I was having problems with overscan till I discovered this command that fixes the overscan problem:

`sudo nvidia-settings --assign 0/CurrentMetaMode="DFP-0: 1280x720 { ViewPortIn=1280x720, ViewPortOut=1190x680+44+20 }"`

Unfortunately I've had no luck in making this part of the startup process and I need to run the command in a terminal each time the pc starts. I've tried adding

`0/CurrentMetaMode="DFP-0: 1280x720 { ViewPortIn=1280x720, ViewPortOut=1190x680+44+20 }"`

to *nvidia-settings-rc* via `gedit ~/.nvidia-settings-rc` but still no luck in making the command permanent for each reboot. Any ideas on what should I try next?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. It turns out that was something I had already tried with no luck (though I may be doing something wrong) ~/etc/rc.local already has `nvidia-settings --assign 0/CurrentMetaMode="DFP-0: 1280x720 { ViewPortIn=1280x720, ViewPortOut=1190x680+44+20 }" exit 0` in it, and running `sudo nautilus` shows that the properties of rc.local indicate that it can be run as a script.  I'll reboot in a sec to confirm, but I don't think it is executing rc.local as a script, or I've put the command into it incorrectly.

Comment: Still no luck, pc continues to boot with the overscan problem. rc.local is definitely executable and has the lines  nvidia-settings --assign 0/CurrentMetaMode="DFP-0: 1280x720 { ViewPortIn=1280x720, ViewPortOut=1190x680+44+20 }" exit 0 in it. Does the line need sudo at the start of it in rc.local?

Answer (score 0):

Add the command to /etc/rc.local before exit 0 and it will execute on boot.